# How do I create an odd-numbered list in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, numbering

Is there a way to automatically create an odd-numbers list in Word 2007 without having to manually change each line number by using the "Set Numbering Value" menu item in the Paragraph section of the Home ribbon?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you don't, unless you do it via code (macro or something).

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case for expediency over elegance. Does not require use of 'Set Numbering Vale' but is a *nasty hack* that could go horribly wrong (so if you must use it, DO SO WITH CAUTION - on a copy to begin with).

1. Ensure there are not adjoining pilcrows at the end of the list (if necessary to avoid this, add a space or something).
2. Carefully select range to be numbered, and choose required format (sequential numbers at this point).
3. Home, Editing, Replace, Find what: `^13`, Replace with: `^p^p`, check Use wildcards, select last `^p`, Replace Format, Font, Size: `1`, Font color: `White, Background 1` (assuming you are on a white background), OK.
4. Click Replace (NOT Replace All) as often (but no more than that!) as required.

[image: SU93255 example]

Sounds pretty tedious but I am guessing your even number aversion is chronic. And dealing with lots of lists in one document this way is not too onerous since Find and Replace holds the settings.